# Forwarding a local port to a remote machine

Tags: django, ssh

I'm using Winscp trying to do a local port forwarding to a remote machine. In one putty window I run the django project on 127.0.0.1:8000, in another putty window I run the forward command

```
ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 -C -N -l <username> <ip>
```

But I can't access through the browser on windows 10 at 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000.
But if I try to open on mac os everything works.

I tried disabling the firewall on windows 10, but it didn't help

Comment: I'd suggest using ngrok ...

Comment: @michjnich How can I do this, could you give an example?

Comment: https://danielmiessler.com/study/ngrok/

Comment: @michjnich Thank you very much! It turned out using ngrok